# How to make progress bar smooth?

Tags: android, android-activity, progress-bar

I create an countdown activity the progress bar move with seconds but I want to make progress bar more smooth.Please help me.
Here is my code if you want then I can upload my app.
The progress bar move with seconds when one second is decrease progress bar increase I want progress bar increase with milliseconds and move smoothly.

```
package com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;

import com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise.R;
import com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise.SaveRestTime;
import com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise.button3;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.cinegoes.www.daily10exercise.SaveRestTime.mypreference;

/**
 * Created by ever on 7/25/2017.
 */

public class t1 extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerStarted = false;
private Button buttonStart;
public TextView textView;
private ProgressBar progressBarCircle;
private final long startTime = 30 * 1000;
private final long interval = 1 * 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer);
    buttonStart = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button);
    progressBarCircle = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBarCircle);
    buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimerActivity(startTime, interval);
    textView.setText(textView.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    countDownTimer.start();
    timerStarted = true;
    setProgressBarValues();
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, pushupe1.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}


public class CountDownTimerActivity extends CountDownTimer {
    public CountDownTimerActivity(long startTime, long interval) {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        textView.setText(msTimeFormatter(startTime));
        textView.setText("Time's up!");
        setProgressBarValues();
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), pushupe1.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }


    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        textView.setText(msTimeFormatter(millisUntilFinished));

        progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
    }
}

private void setProgressBarValues() {

    progressBarCircle.setMax((int) startTime / 1000);
    progressBarCircle.setProgress((int) startTime / 1000);
}

private String msTimeFormatter(long milliSeconds) {

    String ms = String.format("%02d:%02d",
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds) - 
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(milliSeconds)),
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(milliSeconds) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(milliSeconds)));

    return ms;


}


}
```

Comment: add your the code you wrote

Comment: without any code we can't do mumbo jumbo :D

Comment: may be problem  in countdown because on button click in countdown the countdown activity is finished but i am not cancel the timer so when timer is finished then it open new activity which i set in on finish method

Comment: Use your debugger. Put a breakpoint in each place `startActivity` is called. Wait for a breakpoint to get hit then go from there. Also - you _seriously_ need to rethink how you name things. Also also, I _seriously_ hope you don't actually have 10 different activities that are basically identical.

Comment: bro i solve my problem ,problem is in countdown because when i click on button the countdown  activity is finished but the timer is still working in backside and when countdown is finish on 0 secs then new activity automatically open because i set an activity on countdown timing finish so thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Consider making your time interval smaller, and having a larger range of values for your Progress Bar's progress.

Here's some kotlin code that I use in a for a updating the progress of my progress bar.

```
progressBar.max = INIT_TIME * 1000
    countDown = object : CountDownTimer((INIT_TIME * 1000).toLong(), 10) {

        override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
            progressBar.progress = millisUntilFinished.toInt()
        }

        override fun onFinish() {}
    }.start()
```

As you can see, my interval is shorter, and the progress values for my progress bar range in the thousands, allowing for a far smoother progress bar animation.